# How to share image to facebook ActionSheetIOS react-native

Tags: react-native

How to add images from my application to ActionSheetIOS? The example in react-native docs doesn't show me how to do this.

```
showActionSheet() {
ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions({
  options: BUTTONS,
  cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
  destructiveButtonIndex: DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
  tintColor: 'green',
},
(buttonIndex) => {
  this.setState({ clicked: BUTTONS[buttonIndex] });
});}
});
```

Comment: Add the code what you have tried.

Comment: I did just the basic stuff from the react native site. What I don't get is how to send a image that I am using in my app to facebook share using ActionSheetIOS. @Leena

Answer (score 0):

action sheets don't have images https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIActionSheet